# GeoIP and IP to Country in PHP

Tags: php, geoip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the page visitors Country with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965801/how-to-get-the-page-visitors-country-with-php)

I've been searching everywhere, and I can't seem to find anything. I need a free PHP GeoIP/Ip to country.

All I can find is that it gives me the country and small form of the country. I also would like to have information of possible street or coords, city, and maybe host information?

I need this because I am creating a PHP CMS (for myself and clients) and I want to track ips.

I don't really want an API, I want it like a database. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

MaxMind GeoLite database: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite
**OR** pay for the full version: http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing

They also have php libraries to go with it: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable

As for PHP, checkout [GeoIP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) and [Example geoip_record_by_name()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-record-by-name.php)

For a database, you could make your own database overtime... and fill it with cached collected data but I doubt that would be as accurate as MaxMind's data.

There are **many** other methods you could use and couple them with a custom database or even combine it with the GeoLite db: [geoplugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/), [ipinfodb](http://www.ipinfodb.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Google is your best friend :).

you should be able to make it yourself with this information (API):

https://ipstack.com/

Comment: Link goes to 404, just remove /static - http://freegeoip.net/

Comment: updated the answer as the link is now https://ipstack.com/