# Code to block cookies in EU e-Privacy Directive

Tags: php, session, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am using Joomla 2.5.4 extension EU e-Privacy Directive to block cookies and display message about Cookies. I need to know about the code/function which used to block the cookies

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code for that plugin, there are three main things that happen:

1. [Use GeoIP to detect the user's country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424336/geoip-and-ip-to-country-in-php)
2. Remove all `Set-Cookie` headers if the detected country is a member of the EU.
3. Prompt the user if they want to allow cookies, and bypass the `Set-Cookie` removal on further requests if the user allows non-essential cookies.

The second step can be achieved with the following, though note that this removes **all** cookie headers:

```
header_remove('Set-Cookie');
```

If you're looking for an existing implementation, GitHub has plenty of results for [cookie law](https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=cookie+law) and [cookie consent](https://github.com/search?q=cookie+consent). [Cookie-consent-handler](https://github.com/rhios/cookie-consent-handler) is the most generic PHP implementation I found.

See also:

- [One](http://cookieguard.eu/) or [two](https://github.com/danwellman/cookieconsent) or [three](https://github.com/phuu/jquery.cookieConsent) or [four](https://github.com/gbuckingham89/cookieconsent) jQuery plugins
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273638/what-will-web-developers-have-to-do-to-meet-the-new-eu-cookie-law

**Update:**

Regarding your comment about how to remove all cookies except the session cookie, you could replace the `_cleanHeaders` method in that plugin with the following (assumes PHP>=5.3):

```
function _cleanHeaders() {
    $retain = array_filter(headers_list(), function($header) {
        return strpos($header, session_id()) !== false;
    });

    header_remove('Set-Cookie');

    array_walk($retain, function($header){
        header($header);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using this plugin in Multi-Langauge website and i added new session variable in the language module, When i activated this plugin it block the session variable in the language module.  How it possible to prevent blocking of session variable ?

Comment: You'd need to edit the `_cleanHeaders` function in the plugin to achieve that, since it wipes out all Set-Cookie headers as it is currently. You'd need to retain the header that sets the session cookie from `headers_list()`, and set it again after the `header_remove()` call using `header()`.

Comment: ok, is it possible to restore the cookie of corresponding session variable. Please help me

Comment: Variables in the $_SESSION super-global are stored on the server, not sent in cookies (see [Intro to session](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)). A single cookie containing a session ID is used to relate any one client to a session on the server. I've updated my answer to show how to have the plugin you're using leave the session cookie untouched.

Comment: Thanks..i need to know. How the plugin store value to know, the user is accept or decline. Which function keep track accept/decline the cookies  and display the module action to restore cookies and remove cookies. Please give the details about functionality.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the code for the plugin - it's very readable: http://pastebin.com/FCnpSQ7L

Answer (score -1):

Why is there always such an aversion to asking the developer? (it's me, by the way)

Sino Thomas - you flood stackoverflow with questions about my extension - yet never ask me.  Planning a fork?